# java based rabbitmq producer send message with headers

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am attempting to convert a C# version of a rabbitmq producer to one in java and the one issue I am having is figuring out how to send a message header with multiple string values. I think I may have found it but how would I add additional values to header. Current code:

```
 AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder builder = new AMQP.BasicProperties().builder();
 builder.headers(Collections.<String,Object>singletonMap("pId",ID));
 builder.headers(Collections.<String,Object>singletonMap("query",searchQ));
 pchannel.basicPublish("","best_queue",builder.build(),post.getBytes());
 System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + msgcount.toString() + "' MESSAGES.");
```

But only the last header property appears. How do I get to add  more values to the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one replace the first one.

Try using:

```
  Map<String,Object> headerMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  headerMap.put(key,value)
  headerMap.put(key1,value1)
  headerMap.put(key2,value2)
  builder.headers(headerMap);
  pchannel.basicPublish("","best_queue",builder.build(),post.getBytes());
  System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + msgcount.toString() + "' MESSAGES.");
```

In this way should work as you expect